# Android Chat Layout

Tags: android, layout, xamarin

I have this Layout

It works but when the the keybord opens the send button and editbox stays above the keyboard (As I want it) but the keyboard & editbox & send button gets pushed over the ListView (That should not happen) look at the images

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#1E1E1E">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60.0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgMenu" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgwfLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/wflogo" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:weightSum="1.5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1.45">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.05">
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtChatMessage"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnChatSend"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity Code

```
[Activity(Label = "Workflow Management Internal Communication", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

//EDIT
I created the following method which works, but now the problem is this method should be called after the keyboard has opened, Is there a way to listen for keyboard open event in Xamarin

```
void Scroll()
    {
        var list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstChat);
        list.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.Disabled;
        var scrolX = list.ScrollX;
        var scrollY = list.ScrollY;
        _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        list.SetSelectionFromTop(scrolX + _index, scrollY);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking for android:windowSoftInputMode. Try adjustPan and adjustResize options.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to `adjustResize` for the Activity.

Comment: I added it, but no change

    [Activity(Label = "Workflow Management Internal Communication", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]